# How to use infix operators as higher order functions?

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

Is there any way to use infix operators (like +,-,*,/) as higher order functions in python without creating "wrapper" functions?

```
def apply(f,a,b):
  return f(a,b)

def plus(a,b):
  return a + b

# This will work fine
apply(plus,1,1)

# Is there any way to get this working?
apply(+,1,1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [operator](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=operator#operator) module, which has the "wrapper" functions written for you already.

```
import operator

def apply(f,a,b):
  return f(a,b)

print apply(operator.add,1,1)
```

Result:

```
2
```

You can also define the wrapper using lambda functions, which saves you the trouble of a standalone `def`:

```
print apply(lamba a,b: a+b, 1, 1)
```

Comment: In the last sentence, did you mean "which saves you the trouble of an `import`"? Because, as you show, using `operator` you *don't* have to define these wrapper functions (regardless of whether you'd use `def` or `lambda`) at all.

Comment: That is also a valid statement. To cover all my bases, I should have said, "saves you the trouble of either an import line, or writing your own `def`".

Answer (score 4):

Use operator module and a dictionary:

```
>>> from operator import add, mul, sub, div, mod
>>> dic = {'+':add, '*':mul, '/':div, '%': mod, '-':sub}
>>> def apply(op, x, y):
        return dic[op](x,y)
... 
>>> apply('+',1,5)
6
>>> apply('-',1,5)
-4
>>> apply('%',1,5)
1
>>> apply('*',1,5)
5
```

Note that you can't use `+`, `-`, etc directly as they are not valid identifiers in python.

Comment: I like this solution, it is closest to the OP's desired form. It would also support non-standard operators, such as '@', '~' and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [operator](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=operator#operator) module this way:

```
import operator

def apply(op, a, b):
    return op(a, b)

print(apply(operator.add, 1, 2))
print(apply(operator.lt, 1, 2))
```

Output:

```
3
True
```

The other solution is to use a `lambda` function, but "there should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it", so I prefer to use the operator module

Answer (score 1):

you can use anonymous function : `apply(lambda x,y : x + y, 1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Is there any way to get this working?
apply(+,1,1)
```

No.  As others have already mentioned, there are function forms of all of the operators in the `operator` module.  But, you can't use the operators themselves as that is a `SyntaxError` and there is no way to dynamically change python's core syntax.  You can get close though using dictionaries and passing strings:

```
_mapping = {'+':operator.add}
def apply(op,*args):
    return _mapping[op](*args)

apply('+',1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It **is** possible to give the operators `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` special behavior for a class using magic methods, you can read about this here: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

This isn't exactly what you were asking for because this still requires the creation of a method for each operator, but it does allow you to use the operators by symbol in your code.  Note that I don't think this is better than the other methods, it is just an illustration of how you can define behavior for operators:

```
class Prefix(object):
    def __add__(self, other):
        """ Prefix() + (a, b) == a + b """
        return other[0] + other[1]
    def __sub__(self, other):
        """ Prefix() - (a, b) == a - b """
        return other[0] - other[1]
    def __mul__(self, other):
        """ Prefix() * (a, b) == a * b """
        return other[0] * other[1]
    def __div__(self, other):
        """ Prefix() / (a, b) == a / b """
        return other[0] / other[1]
```

And examples:

```
>>> prefix = Prefix()
>>> prefix + (12, 3)
15
>>> prefix - (12, 3)
9
>>> prefix * (12, 3)
36
>>> prefix / (12, 3)
4
```

Of course this method can't be used for a more complex prefix equation like `* / 6 2 5` because there is no way to define behavior for adjacent operators, which will always give a SyntaxError (except for a few special cases where `+` or `-` are interpreted as making the next element positive or negative).